# How to call a method in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-intent, message

I have a question about communication between activities on implementation program of Android.

Here is two activity classes.

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends TabActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(
          "Tab1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_icon))
          .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

_

```
public class Tab1Activity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> list = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)); 

        addColumn("one");
        addColumn("two");
        addColumn("three");
    }

    public void addColumn(String s){
        list.add(new String(s));
    }
}
```

HelloAndroidActivity is main activity.
Tab1Activity is sub activity and display listview.
HelloAndroidActivity include Tab1Activity view.

What I want to do is calling addColumn method from HelloAndroidActivity,
because HelloAndroidActivity is added to new function like TwitterUserStreamAdapter.
If the android receive messages from internet,
application send message to Tab1Activity.

However, I don't know how to implement communication between activities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass data between activities using `intent`, you could put it in the extras with the intent:

**HelloAndroidActivity**

```
intent.putExtra("callX", true);
```

**Tab1Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    boolean callX = extras.getBoolean("callX");
    if(callX) {
       X();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you need to event/listener mechanism it could be roughly like this(haven't compiled this, but should give you an idea):

```
public inerface MyEventListener {
    abstract void handleMyEvent();
}

public class Tab1Activity implements MyEventListener {

    public void handleMyEvent() {
        /*...*/
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         /*...*/
         HelloAndroidActivity.addListener(this);
    }

    protected void  onDestroy() {
         /*...*/
         HelloAndroidActivity.removeListener(this);
    }
}


public class HelloAndroidActivity {
    static ArrayList<MyEventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MyEventListener>();
    public static void addListener(MyEventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    public static void removeListener(MyEventListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(m);
    }

    public static void onEvent() {
        for(MyEventListener m : listeners) {
            m.handleMyEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think these codes are close to what I want to do.
But Tab1Activity have been already created when the application is executed.
so, where should I write "Bundle extras ~~ X(); } }"?
For example, is there listener to receive messages over intent?
If such a listener exists, I'd like to write this code in onHoge(?) method of this listener.

Comment: no there is no listener. you can implement your own listener class. see edit

Answer (score 0):

although you can do it by creating static method , but not right way because it will leave context . pass data to Tab1Activity you have in HelloAndroidActivity throgh intent . 
inside Tab1Activity getIntent and work accordingly .

you can also use onTabChange() to reflect changes between tabs .