# How to invoke a void method in Activity class from a service class?

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a method in another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295735/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity)

I want to call a method `Public void sendmessage(){}` method in a Activity class from a service class. I don't want to return any result to use `StartActivityforresult()` method and I don' want to load another activity to use intent.

What is the best way to do that ? Since I cannot even extend the parent class.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you know it's already been answered, then a quick search would do the trick. Here are two examples found by searching your exact title in Google. [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295735/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity) [Two](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/12458-call-method-another-class-name.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of FirstActivity in SecondActivity and call the method of FirstActivity using this object.

```
    public class FirstActivity extends Activity{

        public void yourMethod(){
           // your code.
        }
    }
```

In SecondActivity:

```
    public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

        public void someMethod(){ 
            FirstActivity firstActivityObject= new FirstActivity();
            firstActivityObject.yourMethod();
        }

     }
```