# Changing tabs without swiping

Tags: android

I would like to switch between tabs without swiping left or right. Using the class below, that is one of the Android Studio activity, I'm trying, by using external events, to move from one tab to another.

How can I do it? What methods should I implement/override?

```
public class Tabbed extends Activity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
    */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
    * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
    * fragment.
    */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
    * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
    * number.
    */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

    /**
    * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
    * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
    */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I can do it with:

```
@Override public void changeTab(int where) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+where)‌​; 
}
```

where `changeTab()` method is an interface defined in the mainActivity.
Also I have in my mainActivity:

```
intent=new Intent(this, Tabbed.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I call `changeTab()` method from the mainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [setCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)) function of the `ViewPager` object for this.

Example:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2); // set number of desired tab
```

EDIT: For your second question, this has been asked a lot on StackOverflow. You cannot just call a method from another activity. You can add extra data to an intent to force the activity to start a function. But this does not apply to you, since you want to call the function after the intent is already created. I think you will have to take a look at listeners for your problem and for your communication between activities. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295735/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity) is a question which is closely related to your problem, which can put you on your way.

Comment: Yes, thanks. For the second question I've solved with BroadcastReceiver's **onReceive()** method

Comment: Good job. Glad it worked out for you. Good luck further!